# How Does Nuget Decide Where To Install Packages Within A Solution

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I noticed a curious thing when installing some Nuget packages and am hoping someone can shed some light on why it happens.

I have a VS 2022 solution with the following layout:

```
MySolution.sln
  MySolution.proj
  CustomLibrary_1.proj
  CustomLibrary_2.proj
  BaseLibrary.proj
```

BaseLibrary is the base and does not depend on anything else.

CustomLibrary_1 and CustomLibrary_2 reference BaseLibrary.

MySolution is at the top and references CustomLibrary_1 and CustomLibrary_2.

I go to BaseLibrary and install a Nuget package using the VS GUI however (right click on the project, Manage Nuget Packages).  I expected the package to be installed into BaseLibrary\Packages, but it gets installed to MySolution\Packages.  There is no Packages folder for BaseLibrary however it does have a Packages.conf.

So my questions is:

1. Why do the packages get installed to the MySolution\Packages and not BaseLibrary\Packages?  It looks like it's something to do with how the Solution also has a project named the same thing because when I look at the project file for BaseLibrary, I see entries like "..\MySolution\packages\SomePackage\lib\net452\SomePackage.dll".

Answer (score 0):

We can see from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file?source=recommendations#config-section):

**repositoryPath (packages.config only)**

> The location in which to install NuGet packages instead of the default $(Solutiondir)/packages folder. A relative path can be used in project-specific nuget.config files.

It may be that the names of your project and solution are both MySolution causing the error of the value of $(Solutiondir).

According to your description, if you want to put packages in BaseLibrary\Packages, you can create a nuget.config in Solution folder and set repositoryPath like this:

```
#Set repositoryPath in project-level files
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile c:\my.Config
nuget config -set repositoryPath=c:\packages -configfile .\myApp\NuGet.Config
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) for more details.